# Angular snackbar staying displayed after going back to the previous page

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a page on which I have two form fields and after clicking 'Add', the snackbar is displayed. But there is one problem. When I create post request and thus the snackbar is being displayed, after that if I immediately click 'back' button, this snackbar is not being removed. So what is the best way to solve this problem?

Here is my `component.html`:

```
<div class="container">
      <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
      (click)="userService.goBack()">Back</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Add New Post:</h2>
</div>

<div class="forms container">
<form #postForm="ngForm" ngNativeValidate>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="formAddService.form.title"
      name="title"
      id="title"
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      required
      >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="body">Body</label>
      <textarea [(ngModel)]="formAddService.form.body"
      name= "body"
      id="body"
      cols="30"
      rows="10"
      class="form-control"
      required
      ></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!formAddService.form.title || !formAddService.form.body" (click) = "formAddService.addForm()">Add</button>

    <table class="table text-center mt-5">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <p class="title font-weight-bold">
            {{formAddService.form.title}}
        </p>
        <p class="body font-weight-normal">
            {{formAddService.form.body}}
        </p>
      </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
```

Here is my `service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { Form } from '../forms/form-interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FormAddService {
  form: Form = {
    id: 0,
    userId: 0,
    title: '',
    body: ''
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  resetForm() {
    this.form = {
      id: 0,
      userId: 0,
      title: '',
      body: ''
    };
  }

  addForm() {
    return this.http.post<Form>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    this.form).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('POST Request is successful ', data);
        this.openSnackBar('Post has been successfully added !', 'Close');
        this.resetForm();
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      }
      );
  }

  openSnackBar(message: string, action: string) {
    this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
      duration: 2000,
    });
  }

}
```

Here is the `goBack()` function:

```
goBack(): void {
        this.location.back();
        this.formAddService.resetForm();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm crazy, but what about `goBack() { this.snackbar.dismiss() ... }` ?

Or dismiss() the snackbar inside the service if that's the correct scope.

From the docs: 'dismiss'
Dismisses the currently-visible snack bar.

https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api